# Format-Volume, hide progress bar popup in GUI

Tags: powershell, usb, powershell-3.0

I have a simple GUI/script to format USB drives for imaging and I am having a hard time suppressing the progress bar that pops up while the USB drive is being formatted.

I am using the below that I want to suppress:

Format-Volume -DriveLetter $Removabledriveletter -FileSystem NTFS -NewFileSystemLabel "ISO" -Force -ErrorAction Stop -Confirm:$false

Comment: Does `$ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'` before running the script solve the problem?

Comment: Nope, I added a runspace and it removed the popup.